# Remove consecutively-repeating values that occur within a date-based timeline

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table that contains user actions based on dates.  The table is used as a timeline of events.  The following example shows how two people changed their job roles through time:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
    UserID int,
    ActionID int,
    ActionDesc nvarchar(50),
    ActionDate datetime
);
INSERT INTO @tbl (UserID, ActionID, ActionDesc, ActionDate)
VALUES 
    -- First person
    (1, 200, 'Promoted',   '2000-01-01'),   
    (1, 200, 'Promoted',   '2001-01-01'),   
    (1, 200, 'Promoted',   '2002-02-01'),   
    (1, 300, 'Moved',      '2004-03-01'),   
    (1, 200, 'Promoted',   '2005-03-01'),   
    (1, 200, 'Promoted',   '2006-03-01'),
    -- Second person
    (2, 200, 'Promoted',   '2006-01-01'),   
    (2, 300, 'Moved',      '2007-01-01'),
    (2, 200, 'Promoted',   '2008-01-01');

SELECT * FROM @tbl ORDER BY UserID, ActionDate DESC;
```

This gives the following, shown as the most recent event first:

[image]

I need to show the table in reverse date order, but remove any events that occur directly after they have already just occured, based on a [UserID/ActionID] match.  For example, if the person was promoted, and then promoted again straight after this, the second promotion would not be included in the results, because it would be considered a duplicate of the previous action.

The desired output therefore, is:

[image]

Following research, I tried to get `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the duplicates:

```
SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID, ActionID ORDER BY ActionDate ASC) AS RowNum
FROM
    @tbl
ORDER BY
    UserID, ActionDate DESC;
```

...But it doesn't quite work, as the numbering is not reset after each different action.  I might be over-thinking this, but am struggling for inspiration because search results are returning the myriad of questions where people are simply removing duplicates from lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use [`LEAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to eliminate rows that are unnecessary.

```
USE tempdb;

DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
    UserID int,
    ActionID int,
    ActionDesc nvarchar(50),
    ActionDate datetime
);
INSERT INTO @tbl (UserID, ActionID, ActionDesc, ActionDate)
VALUES 
    -- First person
    (1, 200, 'Promoted',   '2000-01-01'),   
    (1, 200, 'Promoted',   '2001-01-01'),   
    (1, 200, 'Promoted',   '2002-02-01'),   
    (1, 300, 'Moved',      '2004-03-01'),   
    (1, 200, 'Promoted',   '2005-03-01'),   
    (1, 200, 'Promoted',   '2006-03-01'),
    -- Second person
    (2, 200, 'Promoted',   '2006-01-01'),   
    (2, 300, 'Moved',      '2007-01-01'),
    (2, 200, 'Promoted',   '2008-01-01');

;WITH src AS
(
    SELECT *
        , l = LEAD(t.ActionID) OVER (PARTITION BY t.UserID ORDER BY t.ActionDate DESC)
    FROM @tbl t
)
SELECT src.UserID
    , src.ActionID
    , src.ActionDesc
    , src.ActionDate
FROM src
WHERE src.l <> src.ActionID 
    OR src.l IS NULL
```

The `WHERE` clause in the above query eliminates duplicate rows from the output where the previous row is a duplicate ActionID of the current row.  The `src.l IS NULL` ensures we see rows with no duplicate ActionIDs.

The results:

```
╔════════╦══════════╦════════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ UserID ║ ActionID ║ ActionDesc ║       ActionDate        ║
╠════════╬══════════╬════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║      1 ║      200 ║ Promoted   ║ 2005-03-01 00:00:00.000 ║
║      1 ║      300 ║ Moved      ║ 2004-03-01 00:00:00.000 ║
║      1 ║      200 ║ Promoted   ║ 2000-01-01 00:00:00.000 ║
║      2 ║      200 ║ Promoted   ║ 2008-01-01 00:00:00.000 ║
║      2 ║      300 ║ Moved      ║ 2007-01-01 00:00:00.000 ║
║      2 ║      200 ║ Promoted   ║ 2006-01-01 00:00:00.000 ║
╚════════╩══════════╩════════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

For tables with a large number of rows, you want to reduce the number of aggregates used in your query to the minimum possible; LEAD provides just this by requiring only a single aggregate.  The execution plan for my version:

[image]

Comment: That right there - that has made my day!  *So* simple, yet so powerful.  Every so often (like right now), I learn something new about TSQL that I could use in lots of other places to make life easier, but wonder how I'd ever have learned without posting on SO...!!  A big thank you.

Comment: my pleasure, and yes, StackOverflow has changed my life, too!

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
    UserID int,
    ActionID int,
    ActionDesc nvarchar(50),
    ActionDate datetime
);
INSERT INTO @tbl (UserID, ActionID, ActionDesc, ActionDate)
VALUES 
    -- First person
    (1, 200, 'Promoted',   '2000-01-01'),   
    (1, 200, 'Promoted',   '2001-01-01'),   
    (1, 200, 'Promoted',   '2002-02-01'),   
    (1, 300, 'Moved',      '2004-03-01'),   
    (1, 200, 'Promoted',   '2005-03-01'),   
    (1, 200, 'Promoted',   '2006-03-01'),
    -- Second person
    (2, 200, 'Promoted',   '2006-01-01'),   
    (2, 300, 'Moved',      '2007-01-01'), --<<--- here ActionID is 300
    (2, 200, 'Promoted',   '2008-01-01');

select UserID, ActionID, ActionDesc, min(ActionDate) as dt
  from (
         select t.*
              , row_number() over(partition by UserID, ActionID order by ActionDate)
                - row_number() over(partition by UserID order by ActionDate) as grp_id
           from @tbl t
       ) v
 group by grp_id, UserID, ActionID, ActionDesc
 order by UserID, min(ActionDate) desc;
```

This provides your result but only if `ActionID` of `Moved` is 300, if not, you should partition by `ActionDesc` instead of `ActionID`.

Comment: Argh.  That was a typo in my actual testing code.  Yes, it should be 300.  I've updated the OP.  Can you please explain what you're doing in each step of your code?  It looks like you're subtracting one set of row numbers from another??

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Q2.userid, Q2.ActionId, rn2 order by Q2.actiondate) rn3 FROM
        (select *, Q1.rn - ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Q1.userid, Q1.actionid order by Q1.actiondate) rn2 from 
            (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by userid, actiondate) rn from @tbl) Q1
        ) Q2
    ) 
Q3 Where q3.rn3 = 1 ORDER BY Q3.UserID,Q3.ActionDate
```

the first (inner) query assigns a row_number to every row, ordered by userid and actiondate - then I calculate a row_number same as that, but also partitioned on 'action' - if I subtact B from A, I get a number that can only apply to one group of userIds and Actions - by making yet another row_number, partitioned on userid, actionId, and my rown_number difference and ordered by date, I can then choose row 1, the earliest date.

Comment: Superb!  Can you please explain just what's happening in the code here?  I would have NEVER figured that out

Comment: if you peel away the outer layers, you can see how I'm trying to build towards the final goal

Comment: Re-writing this with common-table-expressions instead of the subqueries might make it easier to understand.